# How to sort values in Pandas based on values in other column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

| int_time | leng | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4123 | 1 |
| 5 | 243 | 2 |
| 7 | 1232 | 3 |
| 8 | 3883 | 4 |
| .. | ... | .. |

and I want to sort values in int_time and leng based on value id. So output will look like this:

| int_time | leng | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 4123 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 4 |
| 5 | 243 | 5 |
| 6 | 0 | 6 |
| 7 | 1232 | 7 |
| 8 | 3883 | 8 |
| .. | ... | .. |

In other words, i want to change row index for int_time and leng based on value in id. Can somebody help me with this please?

Comment: What is the logic here?

Comment: @MayankPorwal logic is that i need to visualize the data for each id. If I do not have data for the given id, I need to write 0 to the leng and int_time.

Comment: In the first dataframe, (3, 4123) has id 1 and the same row has id of 3 in the second dataframe, is that intended?

Comment: @tlouarn Yes, id remains the same all the time. I want to change int_time and leng (something like: take 1. values 3,4123 find which row has id == 3 a place it there)

Comment: Ok I think I understand. Make `int_time` your index and then `reindex()` the whole DataFrame with fill_value=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use merge -

```
n = df['int_time'].max()
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(1, int(n) + 1)})
new_df = new_df.merge(df, left_on='id', right_on='int_time', how= 'left').fillna(0).drop('id_y', axis=1).rename(columns={'id_x': 'Id'})
print(new_df)
```

**output-**

| Id | int_time | leng |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 3.0 | 4123.0 |
| 4 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 5 | 5.0 | 243.0 |
| 6 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 7 | 7.0 | 1232.0 |
| 8 | 8.0 | 3883.0 |